# what is the way to embed php in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

hi I have a javascript file in which I am trying to give the path of the image to it in php like,

```
var arrowimages = {
  down:['downarrowclass', '<?php echo $_SERVER[REMOTE_HOST]; ?>/ultimate-legal-aid/administrator/down.gif', 23],
  right:['rightarrowclass', '<?php echo $_SERVER[REMOTE_HOST]; ?>/ultimate-legal-aid/administrator/right.gif']
}
```

but it not works.
 plz help me to define the path in a correct way.

Comment: "it not works" is not an error message.

Comment: @DaveRandom : no it is not an error but the browser can't show the image it means the path of the image is not correct

Comment: @SmasherHell : quotes are already there '<?php $_SERVER[REMOTE_HOST]' if I use like this '<?php $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] ?>', it will be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it doesn't work has nothing to do with how you embed PHP in javascript. Before I explain what's going on, I'd like to make sure that you know the difference between a client side language, and a server side language.

When a user enters the URL of a page and hits enter, a request for that page is sent to your web server. Because of the way your server is configured, this request will tell the serevr to run a PHP script. PHP is a server side language. That means that the user will never see your PHP code. Whatever this PHP script outputs, wether it is HTML, CSS, Javascript, or some other kind of file, will be sent to the user.

If your output contains javascript, this will be executed by the user's browser once it has been downloaded. This means that in the code snippet you gave, the PHP script will output

```
var arrowimages={down:['downarrowclass', '12.12.12.12/ultimate-legal-aid/administrator/down.gif', 23], right:['rightarrowclass', '12.12.12.12/ultimate-legal-aid/administrator/right.gif']}.
```

Now, these numbers you see will probably not be 12.12.12.12, but some other series of numbers with dots in between them. This is an IP address. More specifically, it's the user's ip addres. So, the path this outputs, would be a path on the user's computer, and the user most likely doesn't have a web server running, so this won't give you any image. You should replace that line with this one:

```
var arrowimages={down:['downarrowclass', '<?php echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]; ?>/ultimate-legal-aid/administrator/down.gif', 23], right:['rightarrowclass', '<?php echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]; ?>/ultimate-legal-aid/administrator/right.gif']}
```

Comment: Although this highlights an issue in the code itself, this probably does not solve OP's problem.

Comment: but sir, this js is using at two or three servers. I do not want to write different IP numbers at different servers. so help me to find the other one.

Answer (score 2):

If your file is .js extension, it will never be compiled by PHP Engine (because browser does not request a php file, apache will simply serve the resource). Add php extension to your js file.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work unless you configure your server to pass JavaScript files to the PHP parser. This can be done by configuring Apache:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .js
```

or nginx:

```
location ~ \.js$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: So what is the correct way. how can I configure server to pass js files to PHP parser

Comment: where will i write this code?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the quotes

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']
```

Comment: quotes are already there '<?php $_SERVER[REMOTE_HOST]' if I use like this '<?php $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] ?>', it will be incorrect.